# How i change size and positions of arrowIcon in Dropdown in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

### How i change size and positions of arrowIcon in Dropdown in react-native ?

I am using this one for my app.

```js
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown';

<Dropdown
  value={this.state.label}
  data={this.state.data}
  pickerStyle={{}}
  textColor='black'
  dropdownOffset={{ 'top': 0 }}
  label="More option"
  containerStyle={styles.dropdowngender}
  fontSize={20}
  onChangeText={(value) => {
    this.setState({
      value
    });
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the node module folder and find the react native material dropdown folder. There is an index.js file, open it and find this block;

```js
renderAccessory() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.accessory}>
        <Image source={require('../../../../../Src/Images/drop-down.png')} style={{ width: 30, height: 12, resizeMode: 'contain', tintColor: '#777777' }} />
      </View>
    );
}
```

You can change the style here or even change the icon by putting your own png.

Comment: but it's never recommended to change the code inside node module as when you install in some other pc, it wont reflect the changes and again it may disrupt consistency

Comment: In index.js file i can see just this line of code. @Bora Sumer

renderAccessory() {
    let { baseColor: backgroundColor } = this.props;
    let triangleStyle = { backgroundColor };

    return (
      <View style={styles.accessory}>
        <View style={styles.triangleContainer}>
          <View style={[styles.triangle, triangleStyle]} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

Comment: @GauravRoy That is the only way to do that since the package does not support style changes for the error. There is 2 options. you customize it or not use it basically.